# Java Swing app causes a ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, swing, classloader, swingworker

I am currently in the process of writing a Java Swing app.

Here is the process that I am expecting to happen:

1. The user clicks a button
2. Several tasks run in background
3. After the tasks are done, a JTextArea is updated with a message that the process is complete.

The problem I am experiencing happens at step 2. One of the background processes utilizes an enum that looks like this:

```
public enum FilePaths {
    MAIN_AUTH,
    MAIN_AUTH_CREDS,
    MAIN_ACTIONS,
    MAIN_FETCH,
    MAIN_META,
    MAIN_RESRS,
    TEST_AUTH,
    TEST_AUTH_CREDS,
    TEST_ACTIONS,
    TEST_FETCH,
    TEST_META,
    TEST_RESRS;
}
```

The execution fails when reaching the first method utilizing this Enum, showing me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: .../gui/guicontroller/authentication/FilePaths

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ...gui.guicontroller.authentication.FilePaths
```

Here is the method from Swing that originally starts the background execution:

```
private class createButtonClicked implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String message = guiController.rename();
            console.append(message);
            if (!guiController.getSessions()) {
                String remove = guiController.remove();
                console.append(removeSessions);
            }
            String addFields = guiController.writeData();
            console.append(addFields);

        }
    }
```

Overview:
- console: JTextArea to add the message
- guiController: controller between the View and the Model
- rename(): runs a bash script using ProcessBuilder (using waitFor() inside) (does not cause errors!)
- **remove(): method call that causes the error and is the first to use the Enum**

What I have tried thus far:

1. Run the same method call inside a JUnit test -- everything worked perfectly
2. Using debugger and ClassLoader when running the app and the Unit test, the difference between the number of classes loaded in Unit test and the app is ~300 vs ~50.
3. Class loader does not display the enum when running the app, but does display it when running Unit test.

EDIT: All of the code is mine, no misspells. Have already checked for that.

EDIT2: Here is some more code:

```
public class GuiController {
    private AuthenticationParser authenticationParser;
    ...
    public String remove() {
        return authenticationParser.remove();
    }
}
```

```
import static ...gui.guicontroller.authentication.FilePaths.*;

public class AuthenticationParser {
    ...
    public String remove() {
        String path = GuiUtils.generatePath(MAIN_AUTH_CREDS, name);
        ...
    }
}
```

The line shown in `remove()` is what causes the exception. The method `generatePath()` does not get called.
GuiController is located under ...gui.guicontroller . AuthenticationParser is located under ...gui.guicontroller.authentication , same package as FilePaths.

Comment: That means that the class you need is not on the classpath.  If this is all your own code, probably you have misspelled a class name.

Comment: 1. can you show us where class `gui.guicontroller.authentication.FilePaths` is defined?  2. can you show where that same class is included on the class path?

Comment: @markspace Honestly, the *package* `authentication` looks an awful lot like it should be "authentification". But good guess.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have good guesses about code mistakes because I've made all these mistakes myself at some point. ;)

Comment: @markspace I tried to keep count of my code mistakes, but my imaginary counter overflowed and it's slowly creeping back toward zero!

Comment: @markspace Like I wrote above, the same method call works fine in a JUnit test and the compiler gives no errors.

Comment: @markspace if I understood you correctly, you mean the classpath in classloader? I have checked that and the class path there is correct, when it works in JUnit. The code structure is as follows: FilePaths is defined in gui/guicontroller/authentication. The class calling FilePaths is defined in gui/guicontroller/authentication as well. No subpackages under authentication

Comment: Repeating: Can you show us where that class is defined?  Edit: you've removed the actual information we need to debug this, can you show the FULL definition of that class?

Comment: @markspace EDIT2: added some more code. I cannot show you what is above the gui package, but I do not think it is relevant, as none of the code from above is called, everything that is called is located inside the gui package.

Answer (score 0):

If you say that the JUnit execution runs fine, while the swing execution produces ClassNotFound exceptions, check that the problematic classes (`FilePaths`) are located within the main source directory, not in the test directory.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I have already checked this. It seems to me that Swing just does not want to load some classes for some reason. Do you know if Swing can fail to load classes if I am not using SwingWorker/SwingUtilities? I have a multi-window app, so I figure it might be a threading problem...

Comment: Hum... Not as far as I know. May I suggest that you create in your project a new Enum class from the scratch, with a new different name, and then replace every reference of `FilePaths` to your new class?

Comment: Have already tried that as well. Same issue as before, I am getting a ClassNotFound exception. But it still does work in the Unit test...

Comment: More tries: Have you already tried to deploy the whole application into a JAR, and then execute it? I suspect the class file or directory might be deleted or moved within the execution of your app...

Comment: I have not tried that yet. Thank you for the idea! Will try and update once done.

Comment: UPDATE: ended up implementing a couple of SwingWorkers, one for each background task, including the one that was causing problems. This solved everything! No more exceptions thrown. However, now I am trying to figure out why the order of these background tasks is messed up... xD.